# Mocking an Object that loads a bean in its construstor

Tags: spring, mocking, easymock

I want to mock an instance of a class that loads a bean in its constructor during its unit-tests. The problem is that Spring is not active during the tests.

My code is:

```
public class foo{ //the tested class
ObjectA oa;

public foo(){
    oa = SpringService.EnumInstance.LoadOa(); //uses spring to load oa
    }
}

public ObjectA{ //that is an enum 
    ENUM_INSTANCE;

    void func1(){...}
    int func2(){...}
}

public SpringService{
    EnumInstance;

    ObjectA LoadObjectA(){
    ...
    }
}
```

If I could, I would change the line

```
oa = SpringService.EnumInstance.LoadOa();
```

with

```
oa = new ObjectA();
```

How can I bypass that?

Comment: Why do you even need a default constructor (it's kind of missing the point of dependency injection)?

Comment: Noted- I updated the code above accordingly (tryied to make the code simple, yet the constructor is indeed redundant).

Comment: I still see a default constructor. Replacing it with one that takes the `ObjectA` as an argument might well make all the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following :

```
public class foo{
ObjectA oa;

    public foo(){
       oa = SpringService.EnumInstance.LoadOa(); //uses spring to load oa
    }

    //package private constructor only used in unit test
    foo(ObjectA oa) {
        this.oa = oa;
    }
}
```

Some people would not be to happy with this solution because you're altering a test subject for testing only purposes, but when serious refactoring is out of the question there is not much else you can do.